# Is it possible to modify group information with a webform or a profile page (not accessing CiviCRM admin pages)?

Tags: profile, webform-civicrm, groups

I'm trying to give access to several users to a webform/profile to easily modify a group's information (e.g Name, Description, some custom fields) without accessing the CiviCRM admin pages.

I haven't found an option to modify groups in CiviCRM Webforms or profiles.

Anyone knows if it's possible or there's any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What group information are you trying to modify?

Comment: Hi Allen. We are trying to modify the name and some personalized fields.

Comment: maybe you can do a quick set up on the Demo site and share it as i am not sure your question is easy to answer without more information, eg what you mean by 'personalised fields' in relation to a 'group'

Comment: I want to let an external user to modify group fields, the default ones, as its name, descrption, etc or other custom fields that we have added in CiviCRM. I'm wondering if the only way is doing it from the administration page or it can be done in a webform or a profile.

Comment: I've created a custom field for the groups in the demo site: http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/custom/group/field?reset=1&action=browse&gid=24